# Physical Address Extension

Tags: memory-management, architecture

[Physical Address Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) can be used to access more than 4 GB physical memory by 32 bit architecture. Does it mean that one process can user more than 4 GB of RAM? Based on [this picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aX86_Paging_PAE_4K.svg) if we have 32 bits to address a memory we still cannot use more than 4 GB virtual memory, right? Then why do we need addressing more physical memory if we cannot use it as virtual memory?

Comment: You can swap memory in and out of the 4GB address space; address space and usable memory are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can only **address** 4GB at once (and under 32bit Windows, you will either have 2GB or 3GB for your own process' needs (depending on a boot.ini setting), since the remainder is used for kernel-mode stuff.)

For Windows, you'll use the *Address Windowing Extensions* - mapping an addressable **window** to beyond-4GB physical memory. I don't know how other systems handle it, but Linux might do it through mmap()?

Comment: Wrong. We can only directly address 4 GB from 32-bit process because there is only 4GB virtual space, which can be addressed by 32bit pointer. AWE is another way of using more than 4 GB memory, and it allows to use, but not allows to address everything > 4 GB at same time. In Linux one can emulate AWE with using of tmpfs. (tmpfs is something like RAMdisk and it is not limited in size - managed by the kernel. You can map some parts of tmpfs to **window**)

Comment: How does your comment contradict my answer? I didn't claim you can address all the memory, but specifically pointed out you map a *window* to >4GB memory.

Comment: Hmm.. It does not contradict. So, please, read "Right" instead of "Wrong" in my previous comment.

Answer (score -2):

Well, if we have a 32bits data bus then we can address 2^32=4GB, that´s a fact. And that means that even when we could have only 1GB physical memory, we can address more than that. However, in that scenario addresses over 1GB, even valid, cause page faults because the memory is just not there!

The SO makes their magic simply catching the page fault and swapping memory to/from disk. That´s the reason we call it 'virtual' memory, because it is just an illusion, a trick (a great one).

Having a 32bits data bus is impossible for a process to have more than 4GB because it is impossible to address more.

Comment: someone understand why the -1?

Comment: if we have 1 GB of physical memory, virtual memory (addressable) is still 4 GB; and there can be some data, eg. backed by swap or by file (think about mmap-ing some file into memory). hmm. But you still says nothing about PAE.